# Data binding order in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, objectdatasource

suppose following code:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="frmMain" DataSourceID="odsMain">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="odsInner" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="odsMain" />
```

Which `ObjectDataSource` would be executed? `odsInner` or `odsMain`? How can I change this order?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Gthompson83: I have a `DropDownList` that is bound to `ObjectDataSource` A. This `DropDownList` itself is in a `FormView` that is bound to `ObjectDataSource` B. `SelectedValue` of `DropDownList` is determined by `ObjectDataSource` B. Simply I want change binding order of `ObjectDataSource`s.